# What is the best solution for Live-cam Service in web application?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc, live-streaming

I am trying to setup a web-based Live webcam streaming service(Using laravel framework php) where a user can broadcast live via webcam (Web based Only).
For example:

User X Starts a webcam-Broadcast at http://localhost/userx while Users Y,Z etc join that room on http://localhost/userx will be able to watch the live webcam/stream.

I was playing around with node.js and socket.io library for realtime chat and it works fine. 
But I have no idea about webcam streaming.

Should i use webrtc? How many viewers can handle the broadcaster if i use Webrtc ?
What is best solution for handling around 1000-2000 viewers?
Any suggestion would help me a lot.

Comment: That's quite a few viewers.  You're better off using a proper CDN for serving your streams.  WebRTC isn't great beyond a small handful of people, at least as-is.  Now, you could implement your own WebRTC server that doesn't act in the usual way, where your server receives streams and send streams, but there is no need for this.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for reply Brad . I am still looking for some solid information to achive this. But do you have any info what is necessary to do it ? I have been looking for using  Pusher library ?But im still not sure .

Comment: I don't know what you should use, but definitely not WebRTC. WebRTC is for peer to peer streams, it's not meant to broadcast a camera stream to so many other clients. You would have to create a peerconnection for every viewer, negotiate ICE, set constraints, etc... Not to mention the broadcaster would need a massive upload to be able to stream camera data to more than a few viewers, since the stream is sent to all clients separately. You really need a solution where you stream the data from the broadcaster once, to a server you control. Then viewers can fetch the data from the server.

Comment: Have you ever looked at things like [Adobe media server](http://www.adobe.com/nl/products/adobe-media-server-family.html) and [Red5](http://red5.org/)? I think those are more in the direction of what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes , i have looked. But the thing is i do not know exactly how to use flash in my php.Just started to dig for it but as i see, first i need to create flash files to get media and integrate flash files into my php  code? I am really confused.And do you have any idea , if it is enough to use something like Wowza not to work with flash files ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [node-camera](https://github.com/kiriapurv/node-camera) module which enables you to access and stream web camera in nodejs using opencv and websockets.

This the command you should run in order to run it:

```
npm start -- [-open] [-wsport websocketPort] [-webport webserverport] [-res widthxheight]
```

where the options passed to run it are:

-open   Open streaming url on startup

-wsport Web socket port for streaming media

-webport    Web server port

-res    Resolution for preview image

-input  Input source. ( eg. ip camera url)

There are few more libraries such as ffmpeg, vlc and OpenCV which are available  using webcam access that can be written as node's native addon

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,honestly i didnt know about node-camera, i will dig for it . but can a broadcaster handle  1000-2000 viewers ?

Comment: This is not a good solution.  It unnecessarily couples serving to the encoder.